# Matlab clustering toolbox

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis

I have just download and install matlab clustering toolbox (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7486-clustering-toolbox)
However, when I run first demo file which is motorcycle clustering example, I am getting the following error.

`Undefined function 'isnan' for input arguments of type 'struct'.`

`Error in internal.stats.removenan (line 54) 
 wasnan = wasnan | any(isnan(y),2);`

`Error in statremovenan (line 7) 
[badin,wasnan,varargout{1:nargout-2}] = 
internal.stats.removenan(varargin{:});`

`Error in kmeans (line 141) 
[~,wasnan,X] = statremovenan(X);`

`Error in Kmeanscall (line 21) 
result=kmeans(data,param);`

Has anyone used this toolbox? If so, how can I handle with this problem?

Comment: What version of matlab are you using?  It sounds like your version of `isnan` doesn't work with structures.

Comment: I have tried it in version 2013b and 2014a. Do you know How I can  handle with this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has to do with a name collision.  The clustering toolbox has a `Kmeans` function.  However, the MATLAB statistics toolbox has its own `kmeans` function.  It could simply be that the clustering toolbox directories are lower in your path than the MATLAB builtin ones.  So the first thing to do is make sure the clustering toolbox directories are at the top of your path, or at least higher than the builtin MATLAB directories.

If that doesn't work, you are probably running into an issue with a major backwards-compatibility break in MATLAB.  Back when that toolbox was written, MATLAB names were case-insensitive, so `Kmeans` and `kmeans` were considered the same thing.  So if you put the clustering toolbox at the top of your path, its version would be preferred.

Since then, however, MATLAB has changed to being case-sensitive (sort of, in some cases, depending on the platform).  This means, in your case, it is preferring the builtin `kmeans` function over the toolbox-provided `Kmeans` function.  These functions are different, leading to the demos not working.

So if the path change doesn't fix it, what you need to do is go through all the code in the toolbox (both the functions and the demos) and make sure the correct case is used for all functions.